# Syncing the font of PlotFrame and PlotLegends

Tags: plotting, fonts

I have a problem with the font's of my plots. Whenever I try to plot something the fonts of the plot and the legend are different. I was unable to find whether there is a possibility to change the font of the plotlegend, is this possible?

Cheers

```
Show[
 Plot[
  betap[eta], {eta, 0, 0.65},
  PlotStyle -> {Red},
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y", "Title."},
  Frame -> True,
  PlotLegends -> {"Model"},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 0.7}, Automatic}
  ],
 ErrorListPlot[lst2, PlotStyle -> {Black, {PointSize[0.004]}}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Data"}]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set the same `LabelStyle` for both plots,

```
With[{style = {FontFamily -> #,
    FontSize -> 18, FontColor -> Black}},
 Show[
    Plot[E^eta, {eta, 0, 0.65}, PlotStyle -> {Red},
     FrameLabel -> {"x", "y", "Title."},
     Frame -> True,
     ImageSize -> 400,
     PlotLegends -> {"Model"},
     LabelStyle -> style
     ],
    ListPlot[{{0, 1}, {.2, 1.2}, {.4, 1.4}},
     PlotLegends -> {"Data"},
     LabelStyle -> style]
    ]] & /@ {"Helvetica", "Times New Roman"}
```

[image]